# scrapy get the entire text including children

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I have a series of `<p>` elements inside a document I'm scraping with scrapy.
some of the are: 
`<p><span>bla bla bla</span></p>`
or
`<p><span><span>bla bla bla</span><span>second bla bla</span></span></p>`

I want to extract all the text with the children (assume I already have the selector of the `<p`)
(second example: to have a string `bla bla bla second bla bla`)

Comment: can you show some code how you extract the data from response body?

Comment: [Beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is great library for scraping. You can use it with `scrapy`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can just use `//text()` to extract all text from children nodes

for example:

```
.//p//text()
```

Comment: ahhh... //text() instead of /text() - what a 1 charachter can do :)

Comment: glad it helps. yes `//` will get all elements recursively after the parent `node`, in your case, `//p`

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 options, either can have their benefits depending on the situation.

**html sample**

```html
<p>Something outside the span<span> and something inside the span</span></p>
```

**Option 01**: use `//text()` -> returns list

```py
response.xpath('//p//text()').getall()

# returns
>>> ['Something outside the span', ' and something inside the span']
```

**Option 02**: use `string()`-> returns string

```py
response.xpath('string(//p)').get()

# returns
>>> 'Something outside the span and something inside the span'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use the css selectors it'd be

```
response.css('p ::text').getall()
```

putting the space between the element selectors and `::text` will grab the contents of the whole subtree, but you might have to parse / join it as need from there.